# Web host with no template

Tags: web-hosting

I've been looking for a free web host where I don't have to use a template. I have my own website fully coded and just want to port it into their server. I don't know if I'm missing something, but every free web host I've come across requires me to choose a template. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I think this information can be useful for you. If you plan to get your website, here is one good free web hosting provider to choose - 000webhost.com

They provide hosting absolutely free, there is no catch. You get 1500 MB of disk space and 100 GB bandwidth. They also have cPanel control panel which is amazing and easy to use website builder. Moreover, there is no any kind of advertising on your pages.

You can register here: http://www.000webhost.com/864177.html

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to web hosting, what you pay for is always what you get. The more expensive companies are expensive for a reason - they can afford all of the costs to maintain and secure your site. Free hosts are not going to treat your site the same way at all.

Venture at your own risk, but no matter what company you look at, always research customer reviews!